# Random in multi variable

Tags: random

I have data:

```
$a = "boy,girl,women,men,baby";
echo "$a";
```

which explode with commas, i want to `echo` random for `$a`,

example:

```
$a = "baby,women,girl,boy,men";
echo "$a";
```

Can anyone help me ?

big thanks for the answer.

Comment: Turn the string into an array, *shuffle the array*, turn the array back into a string. The first and third step should be obvious.The second step can be found by searching [using the suggested terms](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+shuffle+array) (upon reading, you'll run into the appropriate built-in function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function, i.e.:

```
<?php
$a = "boy,girl,women,men,baby";
$a = explode(",", $a);
shuffle($a);
echo implode(",", $a);
```

Run repeatedly this will print:

> baby,boy,women,girl,men
>
> boy,baby,girl,women,men
>
> girl,women,boy,baby,men

etc.